# How to calculate the difference between two time durations?

Tags: time

Here's what I tried

```
$ dateutils.ddiff 02:15:00 00:26:00
-6540s
$ dateutils.ddiff -i %T  02:15:00 00:26:00
-6540s
$ dateutils.ddiff -i "%T"  02:15:00 00:26:00
-6540s
$ dateutils.ddiff -i "%T" "02:15:00" "00:26:00"
-6540s
$ dateutils.ddiff -i "%T" "02:15:00" -i "%T" "00:26:00"
-6540s
```

Couldn't figure it out. Desired output : 01:49:00

Answer (score 2):

```
$ dateutils.ddiff -f "%0H:%0M:%0S" 02:15:00 00:26:00
-01:49:00
```

Comment: Here's output on my side : `%H:%M:%S`. ddiff 0.2.5.

Comment: `$ dateutils.ddiff -f "%H:%M:%S" "02:15:00" "00:26:00"
-1:-49:0
`